# Input stream seems not to be working properly

Tags: c++, multithreading, getch

I am creating a mini project on quiz where i want to force user to give input within 15 seconds. I want user to press enter or any key to move to next question. The program is working fine is there is no timeout but if timeout occurs getch() or any other function used to take key are not working. I have to press enter 3-4 times after which it starts working again. The program kind of hangs after timeout.
I am using a thread to read answer.

Function which is reading answer :

```
void read_mcq_ans() {
   cin >> mcq_ans;
   cv.notify_one();
}
```

Code from main function which is used to check timeout

```
        thread th(read_mcq_ans);
        mutex mtx;
        unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
        bool timeout = false;
        cout << "Ans :  ";

        while (cv.wait_for(lck, chrono::seconds(1)) == cv_status::timeout)
        {
            cout << "\nTIME OUT";
            th.detach();
            timeout = true;
            break;
        }
        
        if(timeout == false)
            th.join();

        cout << "\n\n..........Press Enter.........";
        getch();
        cout << "\n\n";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even though this snippet is quite far from being a [mcve], it suffers from obvious lack of synchronization and spurious `detach`.

Comment: C++ is not my field, but I can’t see 15 seconds anywhere.

Comment: `std::cin >> mcg_ans` is waiting for input. Attempting to read from `std::cin` (or from `stdin` by calling `getch()`) from another thread while that is going on just won't work. Detaching that thread doesn't end it; it simply abandons the thread, leaving it to run on its own.

Comment: Thanks pete backer for your answer. can you please suggest any other method to end the thread when a limited amount of time is passed?